# Facebook needs PHP Curl Extension issue with php.ini file

Tags: php, apache, curl, wamp

I am trying to setup a local version of a website that I can do some testing on. Currently when I open the site in my browser I get this php error:

> ( ! ) Exception: Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension. in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysie.tld\includes\facebook-graph\base_facebook.php on
>   line 19

So I did a bit of reading up and saw that this was most likely due to my `WAMP`server not having the extension enabled for PHP. I did a `phpinfo()` and this output the .ini file that was being loaded.

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini
```

I opened this file up in my text editor and removed the semi colon before this line:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

I then restarted the `WAMP`Server and reloaded my site. Unfortunately, the error persisted and I do not know what I can do to fix it! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out with a quick scan through some similar questions on SO. If anyone is running into the same issue it was due to a bug in the `curl.dll`file that came with `WAMP 2.2`. In order to rectify the issue I downloaded the `php_curl-5.4.3-VC9x64.zip` from this link:

> https://code.google.com/p/justintung/downloads/detail?name=php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip&can=2&q=

I then moved and replaced the `curl.dll` file in the downloaded folder with the `curl.dll` file located in my php `ext` directory.

Restarted `WAMP` and the problem was resolved.